# Why springboot always return 401 when I try to use the resfresh token?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, refresh-token

I'm trying to figurate out why always I get a 401 status when I tray to use the refresh token in my springboot API.

This is the request in postman:
[image]

But the auth endpoind works without problems
[image]

And I don't have any idea why it is going on.

This is my security set up for the endpoinds.

```
package com.bolsadeideas.apirest.auth;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    // configuracion centralizada de la seguridad de las rutas
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/clientes", "/api/clientes/page/**", "/api/uploads/img/**", "/images/**","/oauth/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/oauth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/clientes/{id}").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/clientes/upload").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/clientes").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/api/clientes/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource());
    }

    // PASO 1 crear en bean (metodo inyectable) de la configuracion del cors
    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
        config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Content-Type", "Authorization"));

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return source;
    }

    // PASO 2 registra esta configuracion y la pasa a los interceptores del spring security
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> corsFilter(){
        FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter>(new CorsFilter(corsConfigurationSource()));
        bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return bean;
    }


}
```

As you can see I've added the route `.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/oauth/**").permitAll()` but it still doesn't work.

This is the whole project ( is a edu ´project)

https://github.com/Gerguevara/rest-api-springboot/tree/main/src/main/java/com/bolsadeideas/apirest/auth

Comment: Of the 10 request headers in the 2nd image what is the one that is not in the 9 headers in the first image ? You have 3 different config authorization routes, have you tried running the project with the other 2 disabled ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to use the store, so your are not storing the refresh token and thats tha why you are not able to get it and in postman don't forget to add Authentication basic.